# Expected value of a negative binomial that has finite $n: n \lt \infty$?

Tags: probability-theory

> Cards from an ordinary deck are turned face up one at a time. Compute
>   the expected number of cards that need to be turned face up in order
>   to obtain
>
> (a) 2 aces;
>
> (c) all 13 hearts.

This is a homework problem straight from a chapter on Expectation from a probability textbook. The textbook has a section on finding the expected value of a negative binomial random variable, and says  $E[X] = E[X_1]+ E[X_2[ \dots + E[X_r] = \frac{r}{p}$.

(The textbook defines the negative binomial distribution as the probability that $n$ trials are required until $r$ successes occur. It is assumed that $r$ is constant and $n$, the value of the negative binomial random variable, is unbounded i.e. may go to $\infty$. 
$$P(X = n) = \binom{n-1}{r-1}p^r (1-p)^{n-r}\ \ \ \ \text{for}\ r \le n \lt \infty$$

The problem (a) here seems to want the expectation of a negative binomial random variable, however, the above equation for $E[X]$ assumes that $r \le n \lt \infty$, but in the case of this problem, only up to $50$ cards may actually be selected such that $2$ are aces (there are $48$ non-aces, so the next $49$th, $50$th cards must be aces). In other words, for this problem $2 \le n \le 50$.

So instead of following the textbook's equation for $E[X]$, I tried to find $E[X]$ for (a), given $r = 2, p = \frac{4}{52}$ as

$$E[X] =  \sum_{n=2}^{50} n \binom{n-1}{2-1} \left(\frac{4}{52}\right)^2\left(\frac{48}{52}\right)^{n-2} \approx 19.8134 $$

If I follow the textbook, I get $E[X] = \frac{r}{p} = 2 \left(\frac{48}{52}\right)^{-1} = 26$.

Are either of these answers correct? And is problem (c) essentially the same as solving (a)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the identity
$$
\sum_{k=a}^{n-b}\binom{k}{a}\binom{n-k}{b}=\binom{n+1}{a+b+1}\tag{1}
$$
here is how I would approach (c):

The number of arrangements which get all $13$ hearts in exactly $k$ draws is $\binom{k-1}{12}\binom{52-k}{0}$; that is, the number of arrangements, with the $k^\text{th}$ draw being a heart, to arrange the other $12$ hearts in the previous $k-1$ draws and none in the remaining $52-k$ draws. The total number of arrangements is therefore
$$
\sum_{k=13}^{52}\binom{k-1}{12}\binom{52-k}{0}=\binom{52}{13}\tag{2}
$$
and the expected number of draws would be
$$
\begin{align}
\frac1{\binom{52}{13}}\sum_{k=13}^{52}k\binom{k-1}{12}\binom{52-k}{0}
&=\frac1{\binom{52}{13}}\sum_{k=13}^{52}13\binom{k}{13}\binom{52-k}{0}\\
&=\frac{13\binom{53}{14}}{\binom{52}{13}}\\
&=\frac{13\cdot53}{14}\\[12pt]
&\doteq49.214\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
Since André Nicolas has given a complete answer to both parts of this, I will show how to use $(1)$ to handle (a):

The number of arrangements which attains $2$ aces in exactly $k$ draws is $\binom{k-1}{1}\binom{52-k}{2}$; that is, the number of arrangements, with the $k^\text{th}$ draw an ace, to have one ace in the first $k-1$ draws and the other two aces in the remaining $52-k$ draws. The total number of arrangements is therefore
$$
\sum_{k=2}^{52}\binom{k-1}{1}\binom{52-k}{2}=\binom{52}{4}\tag{4}
$$
and the expected number of draws would be
$$
\begin{align}
\frac1{\binom{52}{4}}\sum_{k=2}^{50}k\binom{k-1}{1}\binom{52-k}{2}
&=\frac1{\binom{52}{13}}\sum_{k=2}^{52}2\binom{k}{2}\binom{52-k}{2}\\
&=\frac{2\binom{53}{5}}{\binom{52}{4}}\\
&=\frac{2\cdot53}{5}\\[12pt]
&=21.2\tag{5}
\end{align}
$$

---

Identity $(1)$ is proven using negative binomial coefficients in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/399213). Let's give a generating function approach here.
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{(1+x)^{n+1}-(1+y)^{n+1}}{x-y}
&=\frac{(1+x)^{n+1}-(1+y)^{n+1}}{(1+x)-(1+y)}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n(1+x)^k(1+y)^{n-k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\sum_{i=0}^k\binom{k}{i}x^i\sum_{j=0}^{n-k}\binom{n-k}{j}y^j\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^k\sum_{j=0}^{n-k}x^iy^j\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{k}{i}\binom{n-k}{j}\tag{6}
\end{align}
$$
Thus, the sum in $(1)$ is the coefficient of $x^ay^b$ in the right hand side of $(4)$. Let's compute the left hand side of $(4)$ in a different manner.
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{(1+x)^{n+1}-(1+y)^{n+1}}{x-y}
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}{k}\frac{x^k-y^k}{x-y}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}{k}\sum_{j=1}^kx^{j-1}y^{k-j}\tag{7}
\end{align}
$$
The sole occurrence of $x^ay^b$ in $(5)$ is when $j=a+1$ and $k-j=b$; that is, $k=a+b+1$. Therefore, the coefficient of $x^ay^b$ is $\binom{n+1}{a+b+1}$. Thus, combining $(6)$ and $(7)$ yields $(1)$.

Comment: I have seen some [combinatorial identities](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Pascal's_Identity), but not that one. Where did you find it?

Comment: @FoF: I have amended my answer with a proof and a link to another proof.

Comment: I saw the [proof](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/595371/104597) but got lost on how to interpret binomial coefficients where the values are clearly negative. I posted a question about this [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/596743/proving-identity-binomnk-1k-binomk-n-1k-how-to-interpret-fa)

Comment: @FoF: all of the binomial coefficients have positive indices here. It is only in [the linked proof](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/399213) that negative binomial coefficients are used. This is why I added the alternate proof here, which uses only positive indices.

Comment: while rereading your answer, I think the $\mathbb (1) \implies (2)$ could be a little clearer. Although it is clear to the reader that $n = 52$, one might not see how or why we reached  $\binom{52}{13}$ (2) for $\binom{n+1}{a+b+1}$(1), and not $\binom{52+1}{12+0+1}=\binom{53}{13}$. This has to do with $\binom{k-1}{a}  \ne \binom{k}{a}$ when we  compare the binomial coefficients of **(1, 2)**,   correct?   A line of explanation could help make the proof read smoother. I did **not** downvote, and maintain my upvote.

Comment: @FoF: The same thing happens when applying $(1)$ to $(4)$. The point of both is that $52-k=(51-k)-(k-1)$. The way I read the formula is that you add the top arguments +1, then add the bottom arguments +1.

Comment: Ah that is a good point. Makes sense. I ran some Matmematica to compute $(4)$ and got $\text{N[Sum[Binomial[x - 1, 1] Binomial[52 - x, 2], {x, 13, 52}]]} = 209950$ but $\text{N[Binomial[52, 4]]} = 270725 $. The numbers look close, although my code may be off.

Comment: @FoF: Oops! That was a copy-paste typo. The lower limits in $(4)$ and $(5)$ should be $2$. Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 5):

We solve the first problem in detail. The second is basically the same, so that solution will be very brief.

**First problem:** Let $X$ be the number of cards drawn until the second Ace is drawn. We find $E(X)$.

There are $4$ Aces, and $48$ non-Aces. Label the non-Aces $1,2,3,\dots, 48$.

Define random variable $Y_i$ to be $1$ if non-Ace labelled $i$ is drawn before $2$ Aces are drawn, and $Y_i=0$ otherwise.

Let $Y=Y_1+Y_2+\cdots+Y_{48}$.  Then $Y$ is the number of non-Aces drawn before $2$ Aces are drawn, and therefore 
$$X=2+Y_1+Y_2+\cdots+Y_{48}.$$
By the linearity of expectation, we have
$$E(X)=2+E(Y_1)+E(Y_2)+\cdots +E(Y_{48}).$$
It remains to find the expectations of the $Y_i$. These are all the same.

Consider the $5$ cards consisting of the $4$ Aces and non-Ace $i$. The probability that $X_i=1$ is the probability that $i$ occupies one of the first $2$ positions among the $5$ cards. This probability is $\frac{2}{5}$.

It follows that $E(Y_i)=\frac{2}{5}$ and therefore
$$E(X)=2+48\cdot \frac{2}{5}=\frac{106}{5}.$$

**Second problem:** Let $X$ be the number of cards drawn until the $13$-th heart is drawn. Label the non-hearts $1,2,3,\dots,39$, and let $Y_i=1$ if non-heart $i$ is drawn before the $13$ hearts. Then by reasoning very similar to the one in the first problem, we have
$$E(X)=13+39E(Y_i).$$
We have $E(Y_i)=\frac{13}{14}$, and therefore $E(X)=\frac{689}{14}$.

**Remark:** The relevant distribution is usually called the *negative hypergeometric*.  Suppose that we have $g+b$ cards, $g$ of them good and $b$ bad. They are drawn in order without replacement. Let $X$ be the total number of cards drawn until the $r$-th good is drawn. Exactly the same reasoning as the one above can be used to find $E(X)$.

The method of *indicator random variables* that we used is quite powerful. There are a number of situations where it quickly yields the expectation, while working with the distribution is more difficult.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, after I read your answer, I thought it was  reasonable (correct, I'm sure :)) and understandable. It seems to me that this problem is open to many possible approaches to the correct solution; while I can read *your* solution and say "ok...looks correct", I do not see why *my* approach did not work out. Is there a fundamental reason why this problem cannot be modeled with the **negative binomial** distribution, as I have attempted?

Comment: @AndréNicolas I now noticed that same labeling of random variables was used in my [textbook here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9u9yFU99BOcaS13bHItSWNZQkU/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: The method of indicator random variables is widely useful. The first easy application is expectation of a binomial. Next is expectation of the htpergeometric. There are many other examples, such as coupon-collecting problem. About your earlier question, we cannot use negative binomial because the distribution is not negative binomial, we are sampling without replacement.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, sorry, had a bad link. Please try the [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9u9yFU99BOcaS13bHItSWNZQkU/edit?usp=sharing) now. Comment edited.

Comment: I got something the first time. Now it wants me to sign in, which I am unwilling to do (friend's computer, don't want to infect!).

Comment: As to correctness, I can guarantee the method, not necessarily my arithmetic. But note that my numbers are the same as those of robjohn, while the methods are radically different.

Comment: @AndréNicolas sorry again -- my (or rather, Google's) mistake. I did not know sharing a file on Google Drive would require others to sign in...dammit.