# Confusion over change of variables in restatement of combinatorial identity

Tags: combinatorics, summation, proof-verification

The identity

$$\sum_{k=a}^{n-b} \binom{k}{a} \binom {n-k}{b} = \binom{n+1}{a+b+1} \tag{1}$$

was given in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/595371/104597), and should be a restatement of the same identity

$$
\sum_{m=0}^{M} \binom{m+k}{k}\binom{M-m}{n} \tag{2}
$$

proven in this [past answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/398771/proving-sum-m-0m-binommkk-binomkm1k1/399213#399213/399213#399213.).  I can follow each step of the proof to $(2)$. I am trying to convince myself that $(1)$ is a restatement of $(2)$, maybe just with a change of variables. It may not even be necessary to use any other combinatorial identities. Still, I still keep getting confused over the meanings of variables when I attempt a substitution. I was hoping someone could please spell out the steps, because I have been stuck here for a while.

Comment: I have adjusted $(1)$ to match the [quoted answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/595371).

Comment: See [Vandermonde's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde's_identity).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original identity $(1)$ was misquoted and that may be the source of the confusion. To get from $(2)$ to $(1)$, substitute as follows:
$$
k\mapsto a\\
n\mapsto b\\
M\mapsto n-a\\
m\mapsto k-a
$$
This substitution yields
$$
\sum_{k=a}^n \binom{k}{a} \binom {n-k}{b} = \binom{n+1}{a+b+1}
$$
but note that for $n-b\lt k\le n$, $\binom{n-k}{b}=0$, therefore, we get
$$
\sum_{k=a}^{n-b} \binom{k}{a} \binom {n-k}{b} = \binom{n+1}{a+b+1}
$$

Comment: Ah I did misquote the identity $(1)$ and that was a typo in the question. I did mean to write $\binom{k=a}{n-b}$.

Comment: thanks for returning to the question, since your answer to my question and your proof $(2)$ already seemed thorough. I didn't want to bother you with this stuff again.